# Changing 3 different button names when a 4th button is pressed - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ibaction

Ok i have edited my original post.

Questions was: I have a button that once clicked 3 other button names will change.

```
from sin to sin-1
from cos to cos-1
from tan to tan-1
```

As you can tell i am doing a scientific calculator. So far i have declared a IBAtion in .h and now i am implementing this in .m

**CODE CORRECTED. for future reference for others.**

controller .h

```
IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;
IBOutlet UIButton *btn2;
IBOutlet UIButton *btn3;
```

controller .m

```
-(IBAction)buttonChangeText:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [btn1 setTitle:@"sin-1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn2 setTitle:@"cos-1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn3 setTitle:@"tan-1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: try this: [btn setTitle:@"your new btn title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Please post the actual code you are trying to use. The posted code isn't real code.

Comment: Are your conditional statements (if statements) checking if two variables are equivalent or are you trying to check if the button's text (title) is already "oldtext"? also you listed controller.h twice... did you mean .m the second time?

Comment: Also I'm very confused how you have an else statement that you then check a second set of variables and if they are true you are setting a third button "buttonname2" to be something... you have "ButtonName", "ButtonName1" and "ButtonName2"? I agree with @rmaddy this doesn't seem like real code at all.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw The lack of semicolons was a good hint that this was pseudo code.

Comment: Ok i just realised that if statement is not the best in here. PS how do i get button name in obj-c?

Comment: @rmaddy if you could have a look at the code i have now, and perhaps help me to determine what should go in front of the setTitle i would appreciate it. Also correct me if my code is wrong or does not fit purpose

Comment: @MaciejCygan Do you instance variables (or IBOutlets) for each button? The variable name or property reference is what goes before `setTitle`.

Comment: @rmaddy Ohhh i see now. will remember it for future!. i got it all working now :) so thank you very much!. I will post correct code in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you to understand, please go with the sender, and use the tag for the button. I will make sense to you. thanks.

```
- (IBAction)changeTheOtherButton:(id)sender {

    if ([sender tag] == 1) {
        [btn1 setTitle:@"Btn 2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if ([sender tag] == 2) {
        [btn2 setTitle:@"Btn 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
```

enjoy Coding....

Comment: To elaborate: you have to hook up this method to both buttons and give one of the buttons tag 1 and the other button tag 2 (in the attribute inspector).